# Width = 100% CSS property doesn't work on mobile. Seems like Viewport gets wrong Width

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, responsive, viewport

I recently launched this website. In mobile view, the header doesn't cover the whole screen width, instead it has a margin on the right side. I can't find the solution to make it work both on desktop and mobile.

This is the viewport setting

```
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

The url is camisite.now.sh

Here is my CSS, the object is simply a header with no class.
I tried changing for 100vw but it is roughly the same. I think viewport-width might be setting the wrong width.

```
@font-face{
  font-family: songenia;
  src:url("songenia.otf")
}

* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: cornsilk;
  }


body {
    font-family: songenia;
    font-size: xx-large;
    background-image: url(background.jpg);
    line-height: 1.2;
}

.input{
  line-height: 1.6;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

  .posts {
    list-style: none;
  }

  .onepost {
  padding: 10px;
  background: rgba(215, 177, 88, 0.548);
  margin: 30px 0;
}

header {
  background: rgba(215, 177, 88, 0.548);
  padding: 2rem;
  min-width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

h1, h4 {
  text-align: center;
}


.error-message {
  text-align: center;
}

.input {
  margin-top: 30px;
  font-size: large;
}

    main {
    margin: auto;
    width: 500px;
    overflow: auto;
    padding: 3rem 2rem;
  }

    .post-form {
    padding: 2rem;
    background:rgba(215, 177, 88, 0.548);
  }

    .post-form label {
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
  }

    .post-form input[type='text'] {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 8px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: black;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
  }

    .btn {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    border: 0;
    background:rgba(25, 17, 68, 0.644);
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin: 5px 0;
  }

  .btn:hover {
    background: rgba(215, 177, 88, 0.548);
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see your problem now. It's because of the way your `.post-form` is made. In mobile mode, the form extends past the viewport. You have two solutions
 1. change the behaviour of `.post-form`
 2. adapt the width of `header`
For option 1, in styles.css:75 for main, the rules are

```css
main {
    margin: auto;
    width: 500px;
    overflow: auto;
    padding: 3rem 2rem;
}
```

The 500px is causing your problem, you can just get rid of it. If your mobile phone width is less than `500px`, then `main` will "spill out" past your viewport while your `header` doesn't do this. Its width stays at 100% of the viewport width.
For option 2, you can make a CSS rule which makes the width 500px when the screen is smaller than 500px

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 500) {
  header {
    min-width: 500px;
  }
}
```